# iOS ScheduleOSUpdateScan MDM command

Tags: ios, mdm

I'm trying to send ScheduleOSUpdateScan request but get ErrorChain.
Any idea what's wrong?

This is the request:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>ScheduleOSUpdateScan</string>
      <key>Force</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>    
  </dict>
</plist>
```

This is the device response:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>someCommandUUID</string>
    <key>ErrorChain</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ErrorCode</key>
            <integer>12021</integer>
            <key>ErrorDomain</key>
            <string>MCMDMErrorDomain</string>
            <key>LocalizedDescription</key>
            <string>“ScheduleOSUpdateScan” is not a valid request type.    </string>
            <key>USEnglishDescription</key>
            <string>“ScheduleOSUpdateScan” is not a valid request type.    </string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Status</key>
    <string>Error</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>someUDID</string>
</dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: request is: <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>ScheduleOSUpdateScan</string>
      <key>Force</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>someUUID</string>
  </dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple MDM Documentation:

> **Only Supervised DEP-enrolled iOS devices and DEP-managed Macintosh computers are eligible for software
>   update management. However, the AvailableOSUpdates query is available to non-DEP managed devices.**

So if your device is not a DEP-enrolled device,the response will be same as you given.